# How to pass value from second class of UITextField to first view class on UITableViewCell in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I tried another code for passing data but it is not working. How to pass `UITextField` value on firstview on `UITableViewCell` on row? Please someone help me on delegate protocol

```
//
//  first.h
//  TextviewExample
//
//  Created by pradeep.yadav on 12/5/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "second.h"
#import "TextviewExampleAppDelegate.h"

//@class second;



@interface first : UITableViewController <secondDelegate>{

    //TextviewExampleAppDelegate*app;
    //TextviewExampleAppDelegate *check;
    second *secondview;
    NSString                *secondFavoriteColorString;
    //second *value;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) second *secondview;
@property (copy) NSString   *secondFavoriteColorString;
@end




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text=@"message";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=secondFavoriteColorString;
    NSLog(@"this second check:%@",secondFavoriteColorString);

    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    second *viewTwo = [[second alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.secondview = viewTwo;
    [viewTwo release];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondview animated:YES];
}


-(void)setsecond:(NSString*)secondtextview
{
    secondFavoriteColorString = secondtextview;
    NSLog(@"this second check:%@",secondFavoriteColorString);
}


this second class

//
//  second.h
//  TextviewExample
//
//  Created by pradeep.yadav on 12/5/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol secondDelegate<NSObject>
@required
-(void)setsecond:(NSString*)secondtextview ;//forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;



@end


@interface second : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *secondtextfield;

    NSString             *favoriteColorString;
id <secondDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField *secondtextfield;
//@property (nonatomic,assign)id<secondDelegate>delegate;
@property (retain) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString           *favoriteColorString;

@end



#import "second.h"


@implementation second
@synthesize delegate,secondtextfield,favoriteColorString;


- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated
{
    [[self delegate] setsecond:secondtextfield.text];
    favoriteColorString=secondtextfield.text;
    NSLog(@"thuis check:%@",favoriteColorString);
}


- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) theTextField
{
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trouble is that you have declared the delegate in the second view, and you are trying to call it from the first view. By the time you have returned to the first view, it's very likely that the second view has been cleaned up.

What you want to do is declare the delegate methods in the first view controller, and when you create the second view controller, you set the first view controller to be the delegate of the  second view controller.

I created an [example project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/DelegationExample.zip) a while ago. It doesn't deal with a table view, but it demonstrates passing a string back from a second view controller to the first view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a tutorial how to share data between viewController:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html

It should help you out to solve your problem.

Comment: u have any example about textfield whis is in second class and pass that enter value on first view on tableview on cell

Answer (score 0):

**From TextField in View1 to Cell in View2**

Take a String in Second View.
Property, synthesize it,
While moving from first view to second view Assign the value of UITextField to the synthesized string right **after allocating** and **before pushing**.
In second view display the text in synthesized string on the cell.

**From TextField in View2 to Cell in View1**

Take a String in First View.
Property, synthesize it,
Take a object of FirstView in secondView and property and synthesize it

While moving from first view to second view Assign the value of `objSecondView.objFirstView=self;` **after allocating** and **before pushing**.
Now in second view assign the value of text to firstViews synthesized string.
And in viewWillAppear of firstView assign the value of its string to the cell

E.g. Your method in the above example must look loke the one below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 second *viewTwo = [[second alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 viewTwo.objViewOne = self;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewTwo animated:YES];
 [viewTwo release];
}
```

Thats it.. Comment if still any problem faced.

Comment: i want to sent value from second class to first it backword